# locationManager didUpdateLocations fires twice on device, only once on simulator

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager

Same code, I'm assuming that the device is actually updating the location twice for some reason, even though I only call startUpdatingLocation() once and I run some stopUpdatingLocations() inside of didUpdateLocations

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    let loc: CLLocation = locations[locations.count - 1]
    let id = 0
    let type = 0
    let number = 0

    createNewDataPoint(id, loc: loc, type: type, number: number)
}
```

In this case, createNewDataPoint gets called twice, creating 2 new datapoints.  It only happens once in the simulator, so I'm assuming it has something to do with the actual device and the GPS since the simulator fakes its location.

startUpdatingLocation() is only in my code one time, on a button.  Basically, you click the button, go go manager.startUpdatingLocations(), didUpdateLocations hits once on simulator, twice on device (identical coordinates) and it creates 2 new data points.

The only other code that mentions anything related is setting the accuracy, filter, authorization requests, and the previously mentioned startUpdatingLocation().  Is there something I can do to make sure I'm not creating twice as many data points as necessary?

Comment: I think you can create a flag, turn it on if get 1 `didUpdateLocations`. I guess the problem is that the `CLLocationManager` update so fast, and `stopUpdatingLocation` need time to finish.

Comment: Although you will still need to use one of the suggested techniques on earlier versions I suggest that you check for ios9 and use `requestLocation` in that case

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Location Manager delegate methods can be called very frequently and at any time.

You may however, apply following algorithm to safeguard yourself:

1. Create a global `bool` say `didFindLocation`.
2. Set `didFindLocation` to `false` when you call `startUpdatingLocation`.
3. Inside delegate call back `didUpdateLocations:`, if `didFindLocation` was `false`, set `didFindLocation` to `true` and then call `stopUpdatingLocation`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Simple enough solution.  Good to hear it's not a problem with my code, it's just that the location is updated so quickly that it fires off twice before I could stop it.  I also noticed that a few times, it was called three times.

Comment: but isn't it possible that the delegate didUpdateLocation might get called again before stopUpdateingLocaiton is called? I might be wrong here but just wanted to confirm. Or system will not call the delegate until the previous delegate is still in execution? Apologies if I am being silly, I am fairly new to iOS. Would it be a good design to add a lock in a delegate?

Comment: Best solution! It's dangerous to set delegate to nil, I think It's important keeping track from delegate's method, like `locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus:`.

Comment: @Abhinav: what if the user switches manually to restricted and then grants authorization again? Won't he find the boolean set to true?

Answer (score 14):

The best way is do as following:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    manager.delegate = nil
}
```

Comment: Thanks buddy for this easiest answer

Comment: should be the selected answer

Comment: if we set delegate to nil then if user charged his location then didupate location delegate function  will never call..
I think its not good idea.

Answer (score 6):

## Best solution for iOS 10.0+

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray<CLLocation *> *)locations {
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation]; // stop location manager
    locationManager.delegate = nil;
    //Your logics... 
    //This will be called only one time now.
}
```

But don't forget to set the delegate again.

Comment: Setting delegate to nil is most important part!

Answer (score 1):

After getting the desired latitude and longitude just call `stopUpdatingLocation()`and set the delegate to `nil`.

In Swift 3:

```
locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation() 
locationManager.delegate = nil
```

In Objective-C:

```
[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation]
locationManager.delegate = nil
```

Here `locationManager` is the object of `CLLocationManager`.

Answer (score 1):

locationManager.startUpdatingLocation() fetch location continuously and didUpdateLocations method calls several times,
Just set the value for locationManager.distanceFilter value before calling locationManager.startUpdatingLocation().

As I set 200 meters(you can change as your requirement) working fine

```
    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.distanceFilter = 200
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
```

Answer (score 0):

You will not get frequently on simulator. and on device when you will move far away then only you get `didUpdateLocations`. just move in a open space so GPS can identify you device location so it get best accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of starting / ending the location update and setting delegate to nil, there is a method called [requestLocation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1620548-requestlocation) which is ideal when your application need quick fix on the user's location:

From the docs:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    // Create a location manager object
    self.locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    // Set the delegate
    self.locationManager.delegate = self
}

func getQuickLocationUpdate() {
    // Request location authorization
    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

    // Request a location update
    self.locationManager.requestLocation()
    // Note: requestLocation may timeout and produce an error if authorization has not yet been granted by the user
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    // Process the received location update
}
```

Use this method when you want the user’s current location but do not need to leave location services running.

Answer (score 0):

@Zumry Mohamed 's solution is right

i try the code like this:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {

   [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
   self.locationManager.delegate = nil;
   self.locationManager = nil; 
}
```

finally this delegate is called only once, i understand now why the problem is occurred, just because manager call the `stopUpdatingLocation`method but system doesn't help us to make the delegate invalid, so we can receive the callback every time location updates due to your `desiredAccuracy` and `distanceFilter` property settings of your `CLLocationManager`, so the final solution is just like what @Zumry Mohamed said, we can manually set the delegate to nil when we `stopUpdateLocation`. hope it will help you understand what happens why this could solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to set a time interval to turn on and off the delegate and so the location manager. A sorta of this

```
var locationManagerUpdate:Bool = false //Global

func scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(){
    // Scheduling timer to Call the function "updateCounting" with the interval of 10 seconds

        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 10, target: self, selector: #selector(self.updateLocationManager), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}
@objc func updateLocationManager() {

    if locationManagerUpdate == false {
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManagerUpdate = true
    }

}
extension lm_gest: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

// Handle incoming location events.
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {


    if locationManagerUpdate == true {
    manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    manager.delegate = nil
    }
//your code here...
}
```

Comment: When possible, please make an effort to provide additional explanation instead of just code. Such answers tend to be more useful as they help members of the community and especially new developers better understand the reasoning of the solution, and can help prevent the need to address follow-up questions.

Comment: Basically it's a simple procedure to accomplish a time scheduled location manager delegate switch. It's useful to prevent the problem of the double fire of location manager itself and keep the location manager updated if the app is running.